# Docker cannot reach container(connection refused)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

> Hi. I am trying to upload the cuckoo container from https://hub.docker.com/r/blacktop/cuckoo and ı am having a connection problem. I start running containers with docker-compose but when I try to curl $(docker-machine ip):8000/cuckoo/status just like the docker hub page I get a connection refused message. I am new to docker so I attached screenshots about my problem. when I look at nmap it says the host is up but the port state is close. I believe that's the problem but I cannot seem to solve that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[this is my first screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPbSl.png) [this is my second screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdtVp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should curl the container port if you use the docker container ip

`curl 172.18.0.6:1337`

docker machine ip is either puplic ip or `127.0.0.1`

so also you can `curl 127.0.0.1:8000`

**Please note**: nmap will give you this result for any up container (service associated to this port by default even it is not running) and telling it's closed

Comment: hi, @AhmedAbdelazim thanks for the answer. I did use docker-machine IP and I still get connection refused. Why am I getting a connection refused message?

Comment: check firewall config 
try to run `sudo ufw allow 8000`

Comment: sir, it didn't work. Do you have any suggestions on how can I solve this issue?  
@AhmedAbdelazim

Comment: are you behind NAT?

Comment: Yes, I am behind NAT right now. what should I do? @AhmedAbdelazim

Comment: curl YOUR_SERVER_LAN_IP:8000 from inside LAN network

Comment: sir, can you elaborate a little further. I am a new learner so I couldn't figure out what you ask me to do. @AhmedAbdelazim